# Share store/actions between two different angular apps using ngrx/store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, angular-ngrx-data

I am here because I need some support on something I need to do.

I am working on a project using NG4 + ngrx/store.

App1 and App2 are basically 2 different angular projects. They are not in the same tree and not in the same app.

I would like to be able to share store between 1 and 2.

Is it possible?

Do you have any advise, hint, how it is possible to achieve that?

demo example will be helpfull for me to understand the concept.

thanks in advance